# Setting up an NSTimer to check if app is inactive

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nstimer

I have an app that requires a user login to use it.  I have a value of X number of minutes that if the app was inactive for that long, it will log the user out so when they start the app next, they would have to enter their login info again.

Is there an easy and efficient way to do this? I'm thinking I have to add an `NSTimer` to my `AppDelegate` and add some logic in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.  I have the minutes stored as an int in `NSUserDefaults`.

For example, if the app has not been used in `60 minutes`, then log the user out (it won't really log the user out then, but the next time the app is launched it will log the user out and show the login screen, etc).

Edit:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSDictionary *userContextDictionary = [dataSource fetchUserContext];
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults setDouble:[[userContextDictionary valueForKey:@"autologout_idle_timeout"] doubleValue] forKey:@"timeoutLength"];  
    double timeDifference = ([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] - [userDefaults doubleForKey:@"Close Time"]) / 60;

    if (timeDifference > [userDefaults doubleForKey:@"timeoutLength"]) {
         NSLog(@"Timeout Hit");
     } else {
         NSLog(@"No Timeout");
     }

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{    
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    double currentTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    [userDefaults setDouble:currentTime forKey:@"Close Time"];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply store the time that the app is closed, and then check it when it becomes active. If the difference between the two is too high, require re-login. Otherwise continue the app where it left off.

In your `applicationDidEnterBackground` method or similar:

```
double currentTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];
[NSUserDefaultsVar setDouble:currentDate forKey:@"Close Time"];
```

And then in the `applicationWillEnterForeground` and `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` (to cover opening from a closed state and opening from background):

```
double timeDifference = ([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] - [NSUserDefaultsVar doubleForKey:@"Close Time"]) / 60;

if (timeDifference > [NSUserDefaultsVar doubleForKey:@"Acceptable Difference"] ) {
      [self reLogin];
} else {
      //continue 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Peter, one thing, what am I doing wrong in this line? `double timeDifference = ([userDefaults setDouble: [timeoutLength doubleValue] ForKey:@"Close Time"] - [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]);`

Comment: @Jon You're trying to set a double on the line that you should be retrieving it on. Use `doubleForKey` instead. Also I reversed the two values in that statement by accident. I updated the code above. Fixed a little thing in the if statement as well.

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense now.  Also, right now it seems to be getting the string value instead of the dobule value, how can I change to a double?  `[userDefaults setValue:[userContextDictionary valueForKey:@"autologout_idle_timeout"] forKey:@"timeoutLength"];`

Comment: @jon it's actually `NSData`, not a string. `[userDefaults setDouble:[[userContextDictionary valueForKey:@"autologout_idle_timeout"] doubleValue] forKey:@"timeoutlength"];`

Comment: Thanks, for some reason it keeps hitting the timeout if statement.  I'm going to post my code in the question if you can quickly take a look.

Comment: Actually, it may be working. The problem was, when you stop the simulator for xcode, it doesn't trigger the `applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application` method so the close time was never getting set.

Answer (score 2):

You can also look into NSObject's [`performSelector:withObject:afterDelay`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector%3awithObject%3aafterDelay%3a) method, in addition to the timer idea you had.

But I have to wonder if you're expecting this method to fire while the app is in the background?

It may be smarter to automatically log the user out if the app is brought back to the foreground (or made active again) after X minutes.

Comment: Definitely smarter, based on your description of the workflow, to simply check the time since the last login in `applicationDidBecomeActive:`

Comment: Ya I stated in my last sentence of the question that `it won't really log the user out then, but the next time the app is launched it will log the user out and show the login screen, etc`, so we are on the same page there, but how can we implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Two types of inactivity:

1/ App inactivity (app not or foreground or device locked).

When your app starts to be inactive, save current time into a variable and compare it with current time when your app gets activated again (methods in UIApplicationDelegate)

2/ User inactivty (does not touch anything)

Create a timer and override `[UIApplication sentEvent:]`. Reset the timer in this method and call `[super sendEvent:]`